# Javascript .innerHTML deletes everything else inside the website

Tags: javascript, html

I am completely new to JS, HTML and CSS, and I am creating a small project using javascript.  The project has multiple divs for boxes

My issue is whenever I use `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'test'` , to change text inside a div, the text in the div does change, but everything else disappears from the website.

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Please include an [mre]. Also, it's strange that you have an element with an id of "id".

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `=`.  `+=` adds to the text, while `=` redefines it, wiping whatever the variable had before.

Comment: That shouldn't change anything outside the div. You should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem lies with the `=`. You're using `=` instead of `+=`.

`x = "text"` will erase whatever value the variable previously had, since you're redefining the variable `x`.

`x += "text"` is equivalent to doing `x = x + "text"`, which is setting `x` equal to `x` *first*, then adding your text.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'text'` you are replacing everything inside the element with the value "test" instead use one of the following examples:

```
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML += 'text'
```

This will keep all the stuff inside the element and it adds the extra text you want to add.

You can also use one of these:

```
document.getElementById('id').textContent = 'some text...'
```

This will only change the text inside the element, and will not remove any elements.

`document.getElementById('id').innerText` does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I need more details to understand your problem.

But I can give you a idea about debugging your problem.

Before Updating value like this,

```
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'test'
```

You should console the previous value. Code can be like this,

```
console.log(document.getElementById('id').innerHTML);

document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'test';

console.log(document.getElementById('id').innerHTML);
```

Then you can see the before and previous value and get an idea about what's going wrong. Also there can be multiple element by same id, that may chane the value in wrong element. Anyway, Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello @gunnersaurus_p150,**

Just a couple of tips before getting to the code, to improve our community:

**First,** let's make sure you have a proper id name for each of your divs, instead of a word such as 'id', I am assuming that you do have each div with a proper name, correct?

**Second,** in StackOverflow it is always best to add an snippet of your code so that we can work with it in order to find a proper solution to your issue, hence, next time, make sure you add that code in your post.

**Third,** you can add a text to a div or change it completely each time, it really depends on what is it that you want to do, but I will put an example for these scenarios in the below code. Forgive my div colors, I picked them at random!

**I certainly hope this helps, champ:**  Keep on coding!

```js
function changeText() {
let textValue = document.getElementById('text2change').value;
  document.getElementById("leftDiv").innerHTML = textValue;
}

function addText() {
let textValue = document.getElementById('text2change').value;
  document.getElementById("rightDiv").innerHTML += " " + textValue;
}
```

```css
#leftDiv,
#rightDiv{
background-color: #ffe6e6;
display:block;
padding:10px;
margin:25px;
width:200px;
height:auto;
float: left;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #FF861C;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #FF861C;
}

#text2change{
width:200px;
color:#0080ff;
height:20px;
}
.btn{
float: left;
margin: 3px;
padding: 3px;
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="leftDiv">This is the change div element.</div>
<div id="rightDiv">This is the add more thext div element.</div>
    <input id="text2change" type="text" name="input" value="Type something, champ"><br />
    <input class="btn" type="submit" onclick="changeText()" value="Change Text">
    <input class="btn" type="submit" onclick="addText()" value="Add Text">
</body>
</html>
```